# Python: How to try again when experiencing a timeout

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a Python program that connects to a server to send it some commands, but occasionally I get this error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

In previous situations like this, I would use something like this:

```
try:
            Do something
        except KeyError:
            do something else
```

Could I do the same thing in this same situation? I.e.,

```
try:
                Do something
            except TimeoutError:
               Do something again
```

And if so, what would I do after the except TimeoutError? Would I just do the same command again?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Could I do the same thing in this same situtation

Yes! You can use `try`/`except` for *any* exception, and `TimeoutError` is nothing special.

> and if so what would I do after the except TimeoutError? would I just do the same command again?

If you only want to retry once, and let a second timeout count as a real error, yes:

```
try:
    do something
except TimeoutError:
    do something
```

(If "do something" is more than a simple statement, you probably want to factor out the code so you don't repeat yourself.)

However, if you want to retry multiple times, you probably want a loop:

```
for _ in range(max_retries):
    try:
        do something
        break
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```

You may want to add an `else` clause to the `for` to distinguish the two cases (succeeded, and did a `break`, vs. never succeeded and just ran out of tries).

---

Since the idea here is usually to deal with possibly-transient errors, there are additional things you might want to add, such as:

- Re-raising the error, or raising a different one, after `max_retries`.
- Logging at progressively higher levels (e.g., a debug message for a single failure, but a warning for `max_retries).
- Retrying with exponential backoff (wait 1 second, then 2, 4, 8, …).
- Pushing the URL to the end of the work queue instead of retrying immediately. You can use `(URL, retry_count)` pairs if you also want `max_retries` logic, `(URL, timestamp)` pairs if you also want exponential backoff, or both if you want both. (Of course this only works if you don't care about the order of responses, or can reorder them at the end.)
- Different rules for different exceptions (e.g., 500, 502, 503, and 504 errors can all be caused by overload on a server or proxy, but the best retry logic may be different—and the best heuristics for 2018 may be different from 2010 or 2025).

For complicated combinations, a retry decorator, like [the one linked](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/) in [jterrace's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840048/908494), is a great way to wrap up the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, nice and simple!

Comment: @abarnert what if one needs to loop through multiple different URLs, sometimes errors like `SSLError`, `ChunkedEncodingError` may occur randomly,  therefore one may want to retry the URL that produces an error （provide that all of them are actually accessible, what should one do in such case? I'm aware that may just be a simple modification of your answer above, but I'm pretty new to python, and this kind of error is hard to reproduce from time to time.

Comment: @JasonGoal You can do the same retry logic for other exceptions—basically everything you expect to be possibly transient. Although if you don’t care about ordering of results, for many possibly transient errors it’s better to push the URL back on the end of the queue (maybe with a marker saying how many times it’s been retried, so if you get to enough retries you treat it as a real error) instead of doing it immediately, which obviously requires a more complicated design.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks, excellent hint, never thought of, I'll reorder the request the URL that produced an error to the end of the queue and records the total times of retrying just like you said. Very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You can catch the TimeoutError like you mentioned:

```
import socket
import sys
try:
  dosomething()
except socket.TimeoutError:
  print >> sys.stderr, 'Retrying after TimeoutError'
  dosomething()
```

You could also use the [retry decorator pattern](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/) on a function:

```
@retry(socket.TimeoutError)
def dosomething():
    # code that causes a TimeoutError
    ...
```

Comment: That decorator is likely to be overkill… and when it isn't, you may need something slightly different… but in that case, the source code certainly makes a nice example that you can tailor to your needs.

Comment: sure, it could be overkill, but it's a general purpose tool that should be in every Python programmer's toolbox

Comment: @jterrace: A link to the source should is certainly helpful to any Python programmer. It's clearly written and well documented, and shows how to write a complicated retry loop and how to write a decorator at the same time. But I can't think of too many cases where I'd use it as-is. (e.g., if I need exponential backoff, I probably need non-blocking, not time.sleep)

Comment: HTTP 500 retries is the canonical use case

Comment: very cool use of the retry decorator, never knew such a thing existed!!

Answer (score 3):

```
def f():
    pass #insert code here
```

To repeat once after the error:

```
try:
    f()
except TimeoutError:
    f()
```

Or to loop until success:

```
while True:
    try:
        f()
        break
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```

Or with a limited number:

```
attempts = 3
while attempts:
    try:
        f()
        break
    except TimeoutError:
        attempts -= 1
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop like the last one when a simple `for` will do?

Comment: @abarnert good suggestion, though with the limited attempts @jterrace's `retry` decorator is much nicer.

Comment: The decorator is also much different. It explicitly sleeps between tries, and exponentially expands on the sleep. If you just want to try 3 times in a row, definitely don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

Please run each example. They are ready!

#### Example 1

```
import sys

try:
    incorrect.syntaxThatIJustMadeUP()
except:
    print((sys.exc_info()[0])) #Now you know what to except and CATCH
else:
    print("You will never see this message")
```

#### Example 2

```
import sys

try:
    incorrect.syntaxThatIJustMadeUP()
except NameError:
    print("There is a problem with your SYNTAX, Dude!")
except:
    print((sys.exc_info()[0])) # In case another uncontrollable network problem occurs, User rages-Snaps IJ45
else:
    print("You will never see this message unless TRY succeeds")
    print("Why not put this try in a loop?")
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"User rages-Snaps IJ45"*?